# Acceleration: $G$ and $G$s difference

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, units

In some literature the acceleration is stated in Gs units. For example, "All structures shall be built to survive 15 Gs of launch acceleration".

However, g-force sometime also stated in G units simply.

Is there any difference? Or, 's' is just the plural form?

Comment: It should be lowercase g, as in the case of aircraft pilots undergoing a 5 g acceleration. g refers to the gravitational force produced by the mass of the Earth, whereas uppercase G is the universal constant of Gravity,  a value different, much smaller, than g. The s indicates plural, as in 3 gs of acceleration, and is often (properly) left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your specification means the structure shall survive an acceleration of $15\,g$, where $g$ is the standard acceleration due to gravity, which is defined as $g=9.80665\,\text{m/s}^2$.

But people such as military fighter pilots, BMX riders doing tricks, snowboarders, etc., often talk about "pulling Gs" and carelessly write G instead of $g$.

Conventionally $G$ is the universal gravitational constant, i.e. the gravitational force between two masses separated by a distance $d$ is $$\frac{G\,m_1m_2}{d^2}.$$

$G$ is *not* an acceleration. Its value is $$G = 6.67408\times 10^{-11}\, \text{m}^3\, \text{kg}^{-1}\, \text{s}^{-2}.$$

Comment: 15g m/s^2 would be 15 m^2/s^4.